# Wrap content around image with Tailwind and Markdown

Tags: css, frontend, markdown, tailwind-css, jekyll

I'm using tailwind on a Jekyll website, and I can't figure out how to wrap content around an image.

This is the Markdown:

```
![image](/assets/images/image.png){:class="h-auto"} Blah blah yada yada.
```

This generates a p tag with an img inside, which seems appropriate.
The content goes under the image unfortunately, and all I tried didn't change that behaviour.

I've tried to:

- take the image out of the p (and put it in it's own... markdown :/)
- float left the image inside the p
- float left the image outside the p
- add flex to the container
- add flex-wrap

I just can't figure it out.
In case my description is unclear, here is my rather basic attempt at being decent on frontend... https://github.com/nofeed/seoengr/blob/main/_drafts/validation.md

UPDATE:
After a bit of messing around, I found out that the problem is that when I add the `float-left` class, no `float: left` is added to the img element. If I add it manually through `style="float:left;"` all is good.
Still sucks though to have this behaviour I'm not able to explain. Why does tailwind not work on that single element?

Comment: This is the easiest and most common thing one can do with HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Rob helpful. Didn't really understand the site you're on, didn't you.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that I don't understand the point of tailwind when it makes fixing such things more difficult than using the basic fundamentals. I wrote that after reading a whole string of problem questions with tailwind, and other such "helpers", here on SO.

Comment: @Rob because you don't use it for that... Mine was a problem with configuration anyway, so actually the problem was that Tailwind wasn't working.